# Having 4 images in each row in a div

Tags: html, css

I want to have 4 images in each row of my content `div` 
After I insert the first four images, they will be shown in the row one. If I add more images the will go to the next row until it reaches four numbers, then it will go to the next row and so on.
I want it to be styled in a way that whenever I try make the browser window smaller, the images would go below each other to make a balanced number of pictures to be shown in each row.

```
<div id="content">
   <img src="pic1.jpg" alt="pic1">
   <img src="pic1.jpg" alt="pic1">
   <img src="pic1.jpg" alt="pic1">
   <img src="pic1.jpg" alt="pic1">
</div>
```

I tried the above code and gave some styles to the `content` div. But I failed to get the desired result.

Comment: Use a grid system from a css framework like bootstrap or foundation or polymer. You are trying to re invent the wheel here without acknowledging it.

Comment: @Sage I am not trying to reinvent the wheel. I am trying to get my desired result with HTML and CSS.

Comment: If you don't care about old browsers, [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) may be the way to go on this

Comment: Can you describe more on how it should be when the viewport gets smaller?

Comment: @Pangloss I want the images to go under each other until they're balanced in each row in a way which can fit the browser.

Comment: Are all your images the same dimensions?

Comment: @disinfor I think I am supposed to force them to be in the same dimensions to avoid showing a mess in the web browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#content img { width:25%; float:left; }
```

You'll likely want to use a viewport tag (in your HTML head)

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

So that you're able to use

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) { }
```

and change it to, for example

```
#content img { width:50%; float:left; }
```

when the images are getting to a size that is no longer practical (too small) to view.

Comment: What does `@media screen` mean?

Comment: So '@media', is defining what is going to read the information inside of the { ... }

For instance 'screen', is for tablets, mobiles, and monitors; but there are also things you'll want to only happen on a printed document (i.e. you can make a print friendly version of a page). Personally I've only ever had use for the two I've mentioned but there are more. ( http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp )

Comment: Oh, and in this specific instance whatever CSS you place inside the @media screen and (max-width: 768px) will, as you may have already guessed, only apply on devices/browsers with a width of less than 768px

Answer (score 3):

As an example with flexbox:

```css
#content {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

#content img {
    width: 25%;
    min-width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
   <img src="https://download.unsplash.com/photo-1429616588302-fec569e203ce" alt="pic1">
   <img src="https://download.unsplash.com/photo-1429616588302-fec569e203ce" alt="pic1">
   <img src="https://download.unsplash.com/photo-1429616588302-fec569e203ce" alt="pic1">
   <img src="https://download.unsplash.com/photo-1429616588302-fec569e203ce" alt="pic1">
   <img src="https://download.unsplash.com/photo-1429616588302-fec569e203ce" alt="pic1">
   <img src="https://download.unsplash.com/photo-1429616588302-fec569e203ce" alt="pic1">
</div>
```

Try adding more images withing `#content` to see how it wraps.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with inline layout:

```
img {width: 25%;}
div {word-spacing: -100%;}
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/bccz4xcu/1/)

Comment: It gives three images in each row. In addition, why did you use `-100%` in `word-spacing`?

Comment: @FreeMind: It gets rid of whitespaces, that are causing to display the last img on the new line. You can use `div {font-size: 0}` instead, if you want.

Comment: But when I add the next `img` tag it will not go to the next line.

Answer (score 1):

html example

```
<div id="container">
<div id="image1"><img src=""/></div>
<div id="image2"><img src=""/></div>
<div id="image3"><img src=""/></div>
<div id="image4"><img src=""/></div>
<div id="image5"><img src=""/></div>
<div id="image6"><img src=""/></div>
<div id="image7"><img src=""/></div>
<div id="image8"><img src=""/></div>  
</div>
```

CSS example

```
#container{width: 400px;}

#image1 {width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: black; float: left;}
#image2 {width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: blue; float: left;}
#image3 {width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: black; float: left;}
#image4 {width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: blue; float: left;}
#image5 {width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: blue; float: left;}
#image6 {width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: black; float: left;}
#image7 {width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: blue; float: left;}
#image8 {width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: black; float: left;}

@media only screen and (max-width: 399px){
    #container{width: 100%;}
}
```

I set the media query to 399px so after 399px you wil see the boxes drop down.

also in your html head put

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

here is my fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/DIRTY_SMITH/3x9ygrf7/